# Does Jenkins CI has special features for Embedded?

Tags: c++, jenkins, embedded, continuous-integration

I have been asked to use [Jenkins CI](http://jenkins-ci.org/) for embedded with justified importance of it. I have explored  about the automatic builds which we can specify periodically ,then other things which we can do is

1. Separation of development and automated tests
2. Automated testing
3. Publishing test result reports
4. Fetching data from SCM.

But I am unable to find anything special in Jenkins for embedded.
Please help to explore whether it has some specific importance for Embedded Projects? As I am beginner to start with Jenkins please correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins is a general purpose tool for setting up Continuous Integration.  Asking what is special for embedded would be like asking what is special about a screwdriver used for putting a screw into wood.

There are many reasons to use CI.  The [Wikipedia article on CI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) is probably a good place to start.

So, why Jenkins CI in particular?  There are a lot of tools to automate CI.  Personally, Jenkins fits best for the projects we have been working on.  The fact that it is very well supported, has an abundance of plugins for almost everything, is multiplatform, and is freely available are all part of what convinced us to go with it for our software development in our embedded products.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Jenkins** to automate your embedded environment.

Example:

1. Checkout your source from SCM - use git plugin
2. Build source using  your ( build ) slave and commit your binaries into your SCM
3. checkout your binaries into your (test) slave and do the testing.

You can control and automate the above mentioned steps by using **Multijob plugin**